# Run React's useEffect at random intervals

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I am new to React and ThreeJs. I am using `react-three-fiber` to animate a 3d model.

I have generated a React component that uses `useEffect to trigger some animations.

This code runs in an infinite loop it seems; I would like for the animation to run once, pause for a random number of seconds between 1 and 9, and then for the animation to run again.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useGLTF, useAnimations } from '@react-three/drei'

export default function Model({ ...props }) {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF('/blob.glb')
  const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(actions)
    actions.someAction.play()
  });
  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group position={[0.16, 0.21, 0]} scale={[1.13, 0.79, 1.13]}>
        <mesh
        ...
```

How can I modify this so that the animations run at random intervals?

Comment: if you add `.stopAllAction()` after `play()` does it only run once ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't say why it's running in an infinite loop. However, you're not passing `[actions]` as a dependency to your effect (in fact, you're not passing *anything* as a dependency) - which means that effect will run every time the component renders.

To get the result you're chasing though, I'd probably create a custom hook that takes care of the "re-run after a random delay" logic for you; something like this:

```
const useRandomlyRepeatedEffect = (effect, deps) => {
    // Keep track of the currently running timeout so we can clear it
    // if the component unmounts
    const timeoutRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const runAndWait = () => {
            effect();

            const delaySecs = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(runAndWait, delaySecs * 1_000);
        };

        runAndWait();
        
        // Cancel the timeout when the effect if the component unmounts.
        return () => {
            if (timeoutRef.current) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
                timeoutRef.current = undefined;
            }
        };
    }, deps);
};
```

You don't *have* to do this - you could just have that inline in your component, but [I'm a big fan of encapsulating custom logic in hooks](https://kyleshevlin.com/use-encapsulation/).

Then, instead of your `useEffect`, you should be able to substitute it with `useRandomlyRepeatedEffect`:

```
export default const Model = (props) => {
    // const actions = /* .... */

    useRandomlyRepeatedEffect(() => {
        actions.someAction.play;
    }, [actions]);
};
```

Note here that `[actions]` is being supplied as a dependency to the effect.